# NSMutableArray contains Objects

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have to check whether an `NSMutableArray` contains an object multiple times (for e.g. the array contains 1,2,3,1,4), I want to know how many times 1 is present in the array. I am aware of `containsObject:` but how to use it for this kind of check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCountedSet` may help as you want to track how many times a duplicate value occurs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCountedSet

Comment: Hey ElanthiraiyanS: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, its really a new and interesting thing, that i came to learn today.I have solved my issue, thanks for your support. I did like this:  NSCountedSet *mySet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:checkedBusinessIdArray];
    int valueCount = [mySet countForObject:m_CheckinedBusinessID];
    NSLog(@"Count for this object is %d",valueCount);
    
    if (valueCount >= 2) 
    {
        businessCheckinCount = NO; 

    }

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to convert it to an NSSet and then back to an array. NSSets cannot contain duplicates. Alternatively copy the values one by one into a new array using a loop, and each time check that the new array does not contain a copy of the object before adding it.

Comment: But i need to know the duplicate values count, how many times the duplicate value occurs in the array, please give suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your object types, but if they can be used as keys for an NSDictionary, I would create an NSMutableDictionary that points to NSNumber objects containing counts for each object instance. Something like:

```
NSArray *array = whatever;
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:array.count];
for ( id obj in array )
{
  NSNumber *number = [d objectForKey:obj];
  if ( number == nil )
  {
     [d setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:obj];
  }
  else
  {
     [d setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:([number intValue]+1) forKey:obj];
  }
}
```

At the end of this code, you are left with an NSDictionary where the keys are your original objects and the values are NSNumbers that contain the number of times that key exists in the original.